# Linq to Sql and T-SQL Performance Discrepancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq-to-sql

I have an MVC web site the presents a paged list of data records from a SQL Server database.  The UI allows the user to filter the returned data on a number of different criteria, e.g. email address.  Here is a snippet of code:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

var temp = SubscriberDB
   .GetSubscribers(model.Filter, model.PagingInfo);

// Inspect SQL expression here

stopwatch.Start();
model.Subscribers = temp.ToList();
stopwatch.Stop();     // 9 seconds plus compared to < 1 second in Query Analyzer
```

When this code is run, the StopWatch shows an execution time of around 9 seconds.  If I capture the generated SQL expression (just before it is evaluated with the .ToList() method) and cut'n'paste that as a query into SQL Server Management Studio, the execution times drops to less than 1 second.  For reference here is the generated SQL expression:

```
SELECT [t2].[SubscriberId], [t2].[Email], [t3].[Reference] AS [DataSet], [t4].[Reference] AS [DataSource], [t2].[Created]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[SubscriberId], [t1].[SubscriberDataSetId], [t1].[SubscriberDataSourceId], [t1].[Email], [t1].[Created], [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[Email], [t0].[SubscriberDataSetId]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[SubscriberId], [t0].[SubscriberDataSetId], [t0].[SubscriberDataSourceId], [t0].[Email], [t0].[Created]
        FROM [dbo].[inbox_Subscriber] AS [t0]
        WHERE [t0].[Email] LIKE '%_EMAIL_ADDRESS_%'
        ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 0 + 1 AND 0 + 20
    ) AS [t2]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[inbox_SubscriberDataSet] AS [t3] ON [t3].[SubscriberDataSetId] = [t2].[SubscriberDataSetId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[inbox_SubscriberDataSource] AS [t4] ON [t4].[SubscriberDataSourceId] = [t2].[SubscriberDataSourceId]
ORDER BY [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

If I remove the email filter clause, then the controller's StopWatch returns a similar response time to the SQL Management Studio query, less than 1 second - so I am assuming that the basic interface to SQL plumbing is working correctly and that the problem lies with the evaluation of the Linq expression.  I should also mention that this is quite a large database with upwards of 1M rows in the subscriber table.

Can anyone throw any light on why there should be such a high (x10) performance differential and what, if anything can be done to address this?

Comment: The common reasons for this are: parameter sniffing and differing SET options (ansi_nulls, ...). Try searching for them.

Comment: If you're running a non-express version of SQL server, fire up SQL Profiler and see if that's the only query that's going over.  It might also give you a bit more insight into where the time is being spent.

Comment: @Neilski - Can you show your GetSubscribers method?

Comment: Difficult to show all of the code for GetSubscribers as it is quite verbose.  What it actually does it build an expression tree based on which parameters have been set in the filter model.  Without being dismissive, I'm not sure it is relevant, as a) the end result is the SQL expression shown above and b) performance for other filter criteria is as expected, i.e. comparably fast.

Comment: I tried running the application under Linq Profiler - it did not show up anything unexpected, i.e. the SQL expression was the same as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not sure about that. 1M rows with a full like can take quiet time. Is Email indexed? Can you run the query with Email% instead of %Email%  and see what happen?

Comment: The problem is not missing indexes or such things. The problem is the discrepancy in duration for identical queries. It should be always slow or always fast.

Comment: I tried changing the query to run Email% and the performance of the web UI and reduced to approximately the same as SQL Server Management Studio.  I can see logically that this format of query can use the Email index, where as %Email% cannot, but it doesn't explain why the performance in SQL Server Management Studio is so much better - unexpectedly so as you would expect that it too would have to run a full record scan.

Comment: Well once in a while (like once in a year) i have the same issue, that the query in Management Studio is much faster as the one used in code. Maybe Management Studio optimizes it somehow (its just a guess).

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/why-would-set-arithabort-on-dramatically-speed-up-a-query that one might be interesting too

Comment: Thank you gsharp, the referred link in your comment to http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html I think goes a long way to explaining the problem, so I have marked your response with 'Answer'.  I'll do some research on what I can do to harmonise the query in my application environment.  Thanks again.